# How do I check if a twisted.internet.protocol instance has disconnected

Tags: python, twisted

I create my connection to a server like this:

```
connection = TCP4ClientEndPoint(reactor, server_host, server_port)
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = Protocol
protocol = yield connection.connect(factory)
protocol.doSomething()     # returns a deferred
```

Now, in some other method, where i have a handle on this protocol object I want to test if protocol is still connected, something like:

```
if protocol.isConnected():
    doSomethingElse()
```

Is there any way to do this. I looked at the twisted documentation and couldnt find a relevant method. Setting a flag in the connectionLost() callback is an option, but I was wondering if I could avoid doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twisted tries to be as light as possible when it comes to stored state. Just as bare factories keep absolutely no track of their children, `Protocols` know very little about themselves. They are mostly callback bags.

Setting a flag in the `connectionLost()` method is the way to do it. For future reference:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

class StatefulProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.connected = False

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.connected = True

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.connected = False
```

**Edit**: note that there's a reason this feels uncomfortable. If you have a method that needs to ask this question, you are probably working outside the callback chain. If you were running code exclusively within the life-cycle methods exposed by the `Protocol`, you may not need this.

Comment: thanks! I am not very familiar with the design practices with twisted. By life cycle methods, do you mean that I should do all my work in the connectionMade() callback, and shouldnt need to ever explicitly call something like protocol.doSomething() ?

Comment: Yes. By running all necessary behavior from the callback methods, you avoid the need of tracking state (which is usually error-prone) because you just do stuff when it needs to be done. Note that this is **desirable**, but no always **possible**. Some designs just need flags like the above. Try to avoid it, but don't wreck your codebase in an attempt to follow best practice :)

Comment: Indeed. I was finding it very difficult to do it all in the callbacks! For instance I had to give the protocol object some additional variables after connecting and before it did any thing, but didn't know how to do that! I had to do `protocol.val = val` and then explicitly call `protocol.doSomething()` instead of doing `self.doSomething()` in `connectionMade()` callback

Comment: That's a fantastic real-life example of what I meant! I hope this new flow simplifies your program